# how to print Nothing in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a Haskell function that returns the first item in the list.

```
h [] = Nothing
h (x:xs) = x
```

When I call it with an empty list:

```
main = print (h [])
```

I got the following error:

```
prog.hs:4:8:
    No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of `print'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Show Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Show Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance (Integral a, Show a) => Show (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      ...plus 23 others
    In the expression: print (h [])
    In an equation for `main': main = print (h [])
```

I want the result to be *Nothing* when I give the function the empty list.

Comment: Try to give the function a type signature, then you will get the error in the expected place

Comment: Also note that your function is currently `[Maybe a] -> Maybe a`, most likely because you forgot a `Just` in the nonempty case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a few problems here, let's start by adding a reasonable type signature

```
h :: [a] -> Maybe a
h [] = Nothing
h (x:xs) = x
```

Now we get an error, we're returning a plain `x` so `x` needs to be of type `Maybe a`. We probably don't want this so we'll wrap it in the `Just` constructor

```
h (x:_) = Just x
```

Now on to your problem.

Notice that this isn't specific to your function, the result of

```
main = print $ head []
main = print $ id []
main = print $ tail []
```

are all the same.

The type of `[]` is `[a]`. Since we don't specify what `a` the type of `h []` is `Show a => Maybe a`. The extra `Show` comes in because we want to print our result. But we don't actually say what `a` is so GHC freaks out being unable to default it.

There are two ways to fix it, the dumb way is to make `h` monomorphic (monomorphisize?) to `h`

```
h :: [Int] -> Maybe Int -- Bad
```

The smarter way is to simply choose a concrete type at our call site.

```
main = print $ h ([] :: [Int])
```

I chose `Int` for no particular reason, it doesn't matter that much. Now `Maybe Int` is printable so we're all set. The `::` syntax works the same as it does for toplevel components, just declaring the type of `[]` in our expression is `[Int]`.

Fun fact, GHCi has more aggressive defaulting than GHC. This means that

```
 main = print []
```

is legal in GHCi but not in GHC. If you're getting a funny behavior, ask for the type of the expression to see what the default is

```
 :t []
```

Comment: s/monomorphisize/[restrict](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_\(mathematics\))/ – I liked your word though.

Comment: @kqr Darn, I was kinda hoping that was the real word.. Ah well

Comment: GHCi allows `print []` and `print Nothing`, though. This is maybe the source of the confusion.

Comment: @jozefg Could you please show the final code?  I tried to put some of your code but they still produce an error on ideone.com.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler eat silent your function

```
h [] = Nothing
h (x:xs) = x
```

but `h` has a type `[Maybe a] -> Maybe a` , not `[a] -> Maybe a`.

```
h :: [a] -> Maybe a
h [] = Nothing
h (x:_) = Just x
```

`[]` is polymorphic type `[a]`, so the  function result `h []`, equals `Nothig` is still polymorphic type `Maybe a`, but `print` can't work with polymorphic type (if we haven't instance of `Show`). In gchi you can run

```
> print (h [])
```

but this case gchi will transform it into `print ((h []) :: Maybe Int)`

But if you have less polymorphic function, like:

```
h [] = Nothing
h (x:_) = Just $ x == ""
```

then compiler find it type `h :: [String] -> Maybe Bool` and `print (h [])` work!